# difference between two rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, difference, subtraction

i have a dataframe as :

```
id|amount|date
20|-7|2017:12:25
20|-170|2017:12:26
20|7|2017:12:27
```

i want to subtract each row from  another for 'amount' column:

the output should be like:

```
id|amount|date|amount_diff
20|-7|2017:12:25|0
20|-170|2017:12:26|-177
20|7|2017:12:27|-163
```

i used the code:

`df.sort_values(by='date',inplace=True)`

```
df['amount_diff'] = df['invoice_amount'].diff()
```

and obtained the output as:

```
id|amount|date|amount_diff
20|-7|2017:12:25|163
20|-170|2017:12:26|-218
20|48|2017:12:27|0
```

Comment: Can you check expected output? If is used `df['amount_diff'] = df['invoice_amount'].diff()` get different output as you with sample data.

Comment: what does (-1) do , can you explain @jezrael ?

Comment: It was only tip ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you need:

```
df.sort_values(by='date',inplace=True)
df['amount_diff'] = df['amount'].add(df['amount'].shift()).fillna(0)
print (df)
   id  amount        date  amount_diff
0  20      -7  2017:12:25          0.0
1  20    -170  2017:12:26       -177.0
2  20       7  2017:12:27       -163.0
```

Because if want subtract your solution should work:

```
df.sort_values(by='date',inplace=True)
df['amount_diff1'] = df['amount'].sub(df['amount'].shift()).fillna(0)
df['amount_diff2'] = df['amount'].diff().fillna(0)
print (df)
   id  amount        date  amount_diff1  amount_diff2
0  20      -7  2017:12:25           0.0           0.0
1  20    -170  2017:12:26        -163.0        -163.0
2  20       7  2017:12:27         177.0         177.0
```

Comment: Wonderful solution... This helped me a lot in my problem too... Thank you very much